# The gradient at the meeting point

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, tangent-line

When two straight lines touch at one point, their gradients are most definitely not the same.

However, when I draw a tangent to a curve, why is the gradient of the tangent the same as the gradient at that point? I'm having trouble accepting this and I was wondering if there was some proof or intuition for this.

Comment: Because of the exact word "[tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent)" (latin: *touching*), which explicitly means that their gradients are equal at that point, *by definition*. Two straight lines *intersect* at a point, specifically without going in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

> When two straight lines touch at one point, their gradients are most definitely not the same.

In mathematics, two curves/lines **touching** usually means that in some neighbourhood, they meet at exactly one point, and that they are pointing in the same direction there. An exception is something like $y=-|x|$ with either $y=\frac12x$ or $y=x^2,$ where the curves at their meeting point are not pointing in the same direction.

[image]

As such, two intersecting lines are not usually said to "touch" each other, nor are two coincident lines.

> However, when I draw a tangent to a curve, why is the gradient of the tangent the same as the gradient at that point?

The curve's tangent at a point is *defined* to be the straight line touching the curve there; so, they point in the same direction there, so have the same gradient there.